# TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not “str”) to tuple Error

Tags: python-3.x, tuples

Can some help me. I heave this code:

```
#Replace Incident Discription
def replace(line):
    #Vul hier in waar je op zoekt, waar je het naar verandert wilt hebben, en hoever daarna de tekst moet beginnen die uit de FLEX gehaald word.
    rename01 = "AUT.BR","Automatische brandmelding. ",71
    rename02 = "BR GEBOUW","Brand gebouw. ",74
    rename03 = "BR INDUSTRIE","Brand industrie. ",77
    rename04 = "BR CONTROLE","Brand controle. ",76
    rename05 = "BR BUITEN","Brand buiten.  ",74
    rename06 = "BR WEGVERVOER","Brand wegvervoerder. ",78
    rename07 = "BR WONING","Brand woning. ",74
    rename08 = "BR SPOORVERVOER","Brand spoorvervoerder. ",80
    rename09 = "ONG WATER","Ongeval water. ",74
    rename10 = "ONG LUCHTVAART","Ongeval luchtvaart. ",79
    rename11 = "ONG SPOOR","Ongeval spoor. ",74
    rename12 = "ONG WEG","Ongeval wegvervoerder. ",72


 # Zoek de term op die gebruikt word in de melding. Vervang deze term en plak vanaf een bepaalde offset de melding tekst er achter.
    if rename01[0].lower() in line.lower():
        return rename01[1] + line[rename01[2]:]
    elif rename02[0].lower() in line.lower():
        return rename02[1] + line[rename02[2]:],
    elif rename03[0].lower() in line.lower():
        return rename03[1] + line[rename03[2]:]
    elif rename04[0].lower() in line.lower():
        return rename04[1] + line[rename04[2]:]
    elif rename05[0].lower() in line.lower():
        return rename05[1] + line[rename05[2]:]
    elif rename06[0].lower() in line.lower():
        return rename06[1] + line[rename06[2]:]
    elif rename07[0].lower() in line.lower():
        return rename07[1] + line[rename07[2]:]
    elif rename08[0].lower() in line.lower():
        return rename08[1]+ line[rename08[2]:]
    elif rename09[0].lower() in line.lower():
        return rename09[1] + line[rename09[2]:]
    elif rename10[0].lower() in line.lower():
        return rename10[1] + line[rename10[2]:]
    elif rename11[0].lower() in line.lower():
        return rename11[1] + line[rename11[2]:]
    elif rename12[0].lower() in line.lower():
        return rename12[1] + line[rename12[2]:]
    elif rename13[0].lower() in line.lower():
        return rename13[1] + line[rename13[2]:]

    else:
        return(line[63:])
```

I use this def to find a special text in a string that looks like: 
"FLEX: 2017-07-10 07:45:34  1600/2/A  11.059 [001201972] ALN P 1 BR WONING Warwickstraat Steenbergen NB 201634 (inci-02)"

I search for "BR WONING" and want to change this is Brand woning. it wil return the text Brand woning. and then the rest of the sting that starts with flex with a different offset.

Wenn i test this def all seems to be good. But wenn a call this function an it is used in a other python project I get the fault: TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not “str”) to tuple Error

second Python project:

```
print("Uitruk STB " + curtime()+replace(line)+groupid+' '),
```

I m looking for a easy fix so I can keep the code and only change small things.
Also ways to do it better is nice but first I would like to know what is going wrong.

Thank y

Comment: It seems like your code is trying to add `string and tuple` which is two different data types and not possible. check data type using `variablename.dtypes`.

Comment: What is returned by the call to `curtime()`? Is it perhaps a tuple? What is `groupid`? Are you sure it's a string?

Comment: I found out that it is 2 things.
1. The comma on line 22
2. the return must be a string. So I add str() before each return.